# CakePHP tree behavior: reordering posts of different types

Tags: cakephp, tree

I have Post model and posts table which simplified looks like this:

```
id | parent_id | lft| rght| title | body | type
```

Type can be 'page', 'new', 'service', etc.

I am rendering different view templates according to post type, f.e.:

```
public function admin_view($id, $type){
    $posts = $this->paginate(array('Post.type' => $type));
    $this->set('posts', $posts);
}
```

To make posts reordable, I use tree Behavior function moveUp() and moveDown(). The main problem is that when I render views which contain only exact type of posts, it may happen that function moveUp() or moveDow() will switch places of posts which types are different. And no changes will be visible in the current view.

Is there any additional scope conditions to pass for Tree Behavior? I looked through all it's code but couldn't find anything that would help me.

Answer (score 0):

Tree Behavior does have scoping feature. Attach the behavior like this:
`$this->Post->Behaviors->attach('Tree', array('scope' => array('Post.group' => $type)));`. This way you can manage separate sub trees for each type. Be sure to set proper scope before all operations on Post model.

Comment: I can't get it to work. Using:
$this->Post->Behaviors->attach('Tree', array('scope' => array('Post.type' => 'action')));

function moveUp() return false, lft values do not change. I tried first detach behavior, or do not declare it in model public variable, but no luck.

Comment: You will need to start from scratch and rebuild your trees with scope for it to work.